# When is the telegraphic stage in English?

Tags: reference-request, language-acquisition

If you Google "telegraphic speech," many lay articles ([1](https://www.healthline.com/health/childrens-health/telegraphic-speech#age-it-starts), [2](https://www.momjunction.com/articles/telegraphic-speech-examples-age-activities_00758136/), and the [APA dictionary](https://dictionary.apa.org/telegraphic-speech)) mention an approximate age range of 18-24/30 months for the production of telegraphic speech.

However, I have been struggling to find academic resources describing the bounds of this production. Can someone point to academic research describing when children produce telegraphic speech?

Comment: The bounds of production??// I suggest you enter the term in Google books. There are lots of academic books/articles.

Comment: One probably should look in child psychology books. These bounds are so well established that they are accepted as the basis of education system in many countries - 3 year old children are generally expected to be able to speak and are taught alphabet, writing their name, etc. Not being able to speak at the age of 3 is treated as a retardation, etc. You can also pose a question in the Parenting community.